# Why does the output of cargo build contain unreadable characters when the build fails?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to build a simple [guessing-game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) as described in the documentation.

```
use std::io;
//use rand::Rng; is not included 

fn main() {
     println!("Guess the number!");
     let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
     println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);
     println!("Please input your guess.");
     let mut guess = String::new();
     io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
          .expect("Failed to read line");
     println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

The above code will not compile due to missing `rand::Rng` library (note comment).

The problem is that the result of the `cargo build` command consists of unreadable characters:

[image]

I am using CentOS 7, Rust version 1.32.0 and Cargo Version 1.32.0. I was able to verify the terminal encoding before and after running `cargo-build` and it was not changed.

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: That's probably not the main issue here, but... Do you always compile and run random untrusted code pulled from the internet under `/root`? :)

Comment: The *encoding* may be unchanged, but that only affects programs run *in* the terminal. The terminal has its own setting determining what *charset* to use and, by some coincidence, you've convinced Cargo to emit one of the control sequences that tells the terminal to change the charset (like changing the font). Type `reset` to get it back and maybe consider using a different terminal if you want to see all the pretty colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cargo build --color=never` to not use colors.

---

To help you fix the problem while keeping colors, we would need more information. Eg. what terminal emulator you use, what is your locale, etc.

Comment: It would be far less annoying if the default were "use the normal terminal color scheme" and the option instead were `--color=randomly-festoon-with-distracting-and-illegible-color`

Comment: @jhfrontz “use the normal terminal color scheme” is exactly what the default is.

Comment: Huh, weird -- not sure why it (and only it) is using bright yellow with a white background (when trying to emphasize something, no less).